# Rally: How to make apps compatible with the time box filter?

Tags: rally

When displaying several apps on a page, I am aware that I can use a global filter such as a release or iteration filter rather than having a release or iteration filter for each app.  However, the global filter does not seem to work properly for the Iteration Summary app but it works with individual filter. I have looked at the source code for the Iteration Summary app to make it compatible with the global filter (aka time box filter).  Please refer to http://developer.rallydev.com/help/Apps-Timebox-Filtered-Dashboards for more information.

Also, another concern for the custom grid app how do I make it so that I do not have to hard code the query like Iteration.Name = "IR 1" but instead use the global filter data to do the query.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom grid should automatically respect the global timebox filter on the dashboard.  It will AND on the timebox filter to any query entered (so there is no need to manually add it).

The Iteration Summary App should work with the global filter.  Could you give more info on what the problem is?

Comment: The apps work very well when using local filters.  However, when using global filters, the iteration summary app just displays something like 0% accepted when regardless of the iteration selected.  I have confirmed that in the current iteration as well as previous iterations the percentage accepted is more than 0% indeed and the iteration summary app displays the expected results when local filters are used.On another note, I think you pointed me in the right direction with regard to custom grid.  I do not have to query anything to make it compatible with the global

Comment: With custom grid you shouldn't have to do anything- it should just work.  I looked into it and we have an active defect for the issue you are reporting with the Iteration Summary App.  It should be fixed soon.

Comment: I was curious when this defect will be fixed.

Comment: It should be fixed in the 2012.08.04 release.